# Flattening a Parent Child relationship with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and looking a way to flatten a multi level parent child relationship using pandas or python.I am having csv file which contains data like below .

For each child, I want to traverse from parent till child . Any kind of help is appreciated.

Input

```
--------------------
Child,Parent,Country
--------------------
A,TOP LEVEL,GERMANY

B,A,USA

C,B,JAPAN

D,TOP LEVEL,INDIA

E,D,CHINA
```

output

```
--------------------
HIERARCHY,COUNTRY
--------------------
A,GERMANY

A.B,USA

A.B.C,JAPAN

D,INDIA

D.E,CHINA
```

Comment: Why not just directly have the parent child relationship in the output in terms of the country relationships, instead of mitigating it through these other mappings?

Comment: Shouldn't the third line be `C,B,A,JAPAN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `networkx` and a Directed Graph, in case things aren't necessarily ordered properly in your original DataFrame. First, we need to fix the DataFrame so that `TOP LEVEL` is not a parent and the country is used.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df['True_Parent'] = df['Parent'].mask(df['Parent'].eq('TOP LEVEL')).fillna(df['Country'])
#  Child     Parent  Country True_Parent
#0     A  TOP LEVEL  GERMANY     GERMANY
#1     B          A      USA           A
#2     C          B    JAPAN           B
#3     D  TOP LEVEL    INDIA       INDIA
#4     E          D    CHINA           D
```

Now create the directed Graph

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='True_Parent', target='Child', 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

What we want are all of the predecessors, recursively:

```
def all_preds(G, target):
    preds=[target]
    for p in list(G.predecessors(target)):
        preds += all_preds(G, p)
    return preds

df['Hierarchy'] = ['.'.join(all_preds(G, country)[:-1][::-1]) for country in df['Child'].unique()]
#  Child     Parent  Country True_Parent Hierarchy
#0     A  TOP LEVEL  GERMANY     GERMANY         A
#1     B          A      USA           A       A.B
#2     C          B    JAPAN           B     A.B.C
#3     D  TOP LEVEL    INDIA       INDIA         D
#4     E          D    CHINA           D       D.E
```

---

It is a little weird to have the relationships like that. In the first group you have TOP LEVEL, A, B, C and yet only 3 unique countries. If you wanted to create a more succinct parent-child mapping we can do that before making the graphs:

```
(df.groupby(df.Parent.eq('TOP LEVEL').cumsum())
   .apply(lambda gp: gp.replace(gp.set_index('Child').Country.to_dict()))
   .query('Parent != "TOP LEVEL"')[['Child', 'Parent']])

#   Child   Parent
#1    USA  GERMANY
#2  JAPAN      USA
#4  CHINA    INDIA
```

Comment: Thank you @ALollz . I required only the hierarchy along with the corresponding Country value . But I can just drop True_Parent to get the desired output.