# Iterate through a pandas dataframe to get a specific output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which I want to iterate to get a specific result.

Portion of the dataframe df (the name of the columns are `guid1` and `guid2`) :
[DataSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYMGP.png)

```
 guid1  guid2
 A865   OR4
 A875   OR4
 OR4    JN1397
 JN1400 JN1401
 JN1402 DEL131KS-
 Unset  AND1
```

**Interpretation :** Both `A865` and `A875` are connected to `OR4` and `OR4` is then connected to `JN1397` (it's a representation of a logical diagram).
My goal here is to iterate through the dataframe (to verify if there is any connections) to get a string result (as follows) in which I interpret the different connections:

```
A865, A875, OR4, JN1397
```

I already posted this question and it has been closed for lack of clarity, I really hope it's clear enough now because I really need some help here..

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60993140/134204) shows how to use `networkx` to flatten a parent\child hierarchy in a dataframe.

Comment: Do you always have a connection? What happens if not? Is your goal only to identify if all uids are connected or do you really need the path?

Comment: I have a 300 row dataframe, what I need is to identify all connections and write the paths down, and if there is no connection, I just have to ignore the rows

Comment: Can you update the question with such an example? What if you have 2 groups, which one(s) should you keep/drop?

Comment: I've edited and added some rows which I won't be using in my iteration cause there is no visual connection whatsoever.

Comment: It's still ambiguous how the "linear path" construction would generalize for larger graphs.

Comment: awesome this merge of question I wasn't aware of it! Thanks moderator ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) to handle your graph.

This is how it looks (showing as directed graph, but using an undirected graph later):

[image]

You can create the graph using:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='guid1', target='guid2')
```

Then keep the subgraph that contains your initial node:

```
start = df['guid1'].iloc[0] # 'A865'

keep = nx.node_connected_component(G, start)
# {'A865', 'A875', 'JN1397', 'OR4'}
```

If you really want the pseudo-path in original order of the DataFrame:

```
key = {v: k for k,v in enumerate(df['guid1'].drop_duplicates())}
# {'A865': 0, 'A875': 1, 'OR4': 2, 'JN1400': 3, 'JN1402': 4, 'Unset': 5}

path = ' -> '.join(sorted(keep, key=lambda x: key.get(x, float('inf'))))
```

output: `'A865 -> A875 -> OR4 -> JN1397'`

Comment: Thank you @mozway , I managed to adapt it to my dataset, and it's working brilliantly!

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to manually iterate through the rows and columns to check for its relation. For example, you can use .corr() on your DataFrame to obtain a correlation matrix - note: by default, .corr() returns Pearson's correlation.

```
df.corr()
```

To help visualize you can use:

```
corr = df.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr, annot=True)
```

As mentioned by @bpfrd, since your values are categorical, you need to conduct a categorical encoding first (i.e. dummy, one-hot, label, etc. encoding).

Otherwise, use correlational measures that are for categorical data, i.e. Chi-squared, Cramer's V, etc. You can find more in this site: https://towardsdatascience.com/levels-of-measurement-statistics-and-python-implementations-8ff8e7867d0b

Comment: It's only correct if they are interested in correlation! but their data seems like string.

Comment: True, then they would probably have to use categorical encoding which I will make note of

Comment: as @bpfrd said, I am not interested in correlation, and yes the data type is string. I am just looking for a way to look into the df to see if there is any common elements in 2 rows to then get a string output describing that.

Answer (score -3):

If you have to iterate through your dataframe you can do that by:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
  #row[your_col]
```

You can select columns in each `row` using `row[your_col]`. but depending on your relation you can use `apply` and `transform` as well.